# Android: How to programmatically invoke PIN screen directly?

Tags: android, screen

Currently with the 2.2 API I am able to lock the device via [DevicePolicyManager.lockNow()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#lockNow%28%29).

Having called that method I get a standard Android lock screen. I have to unlock the device to see the next sceen I'm actually interested in - the PIN screen.

So, my question is "Is it possible to invoke PIN screen directly (without getting to the lock screen first)?".

Comment: @njzk2: Unfortunatelly not. And we finally decided even to not use `DevicePolicyManager` at all in favour of our custom pin screen activity because we have much more control over it.

Answer (score 1):

you can start an intent with action set to DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD

Comment: no it shows change password screen, after that once your changes password u get pass word change intent and u can call lockNow on tat

Comment: Thanks, for the feedback. However, sorry, that's not exactly what I need. Because actually what I need is to be sure it is the original device user who holds the device right now. So changing password each time when I'd like to identify user is not an option. As for now we are quite comfortable with the current unlock inconviniece.